# Wordpress CPT not showing title with diacritic signs in admin panel

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, diacritics

In admin panel, cpt titles with diacritic signs are not shown and i dont know what happened. On my test server it is all good, but when i uploaded all changes to client's server i got this problem.

Admin panel on test server:
[test server admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STrZB.png)

Admin panel on client's server:
[client server admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iv9G.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check your database collation and character set in your test server and put it in your client server.

For more info:
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-collation/
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-table.html